# Razor .koform('submit') to ASPX .koform('submit') how to

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, knockout.js

I changed a View into a PartialView so now I need to use ASPX instead of Razor. However, I can't find anywhere how I can change the syntax of

```
<button onclick="$('#@Model.meta.modelname').koform('submit');">
```

so that it works with in ASPX.

full code:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="iVention.Web.Framework.Core.ViewUserControl<iVention.Web.Framework.Areas.Administration.Models.NoteModel>" %>
<% using (UI.koform(Model, null))
{ %>
[...]
<div class="dialogButtons">
    <button onclick="$('#@Model.meta.modelname').koform('submit');">
        Save</button>
</div>
<%}%>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `<%: %>`

```
<button onclick="$('#<%: Model.meta.modelname %>').koform('submit');">
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use standard ASPX interpolation:

```
<%: Model.meta.modelname %>
```

Note that IntelliSense won't work on ASPX interpolations in attributes until Visual Studio 11.